# How to sort list of strings containing numbers in it using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

```
Input -> {"rajesh|51|32|asd", "nitin|71|27|asd", "test|11|30|asd"} 

output -> {"test|11|30|asd", "rajesh|51|32|asd" ,"nitin|71|27|asd"}
```

How I can *sort* the above `List<string>` by using *LINQ*.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Natural Sort Order in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

you can get number from string using `Regex.Match(inputString, @"\d+")` and sort the list by this number using `linq.OrderBy`:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "rajesh|51|32|asd", "nitin|71|27|asd", "test|11|30|asd" };
var result=list.OrderBy(i => Regex.Match(i, @"\d+").Value).ToList();
```

result:

```
1=> "test|11|30|asd"
2=>"rajesh|51|32|asd" 
3=>"nitin|71|27|asd"
```

**Note:**
There are two numbers in the string and you didn't say which number to sort by. But the result shows that you mean the first number